# Xcode 4.3.2 error when run app on iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I just created a `Tab-Based` Application template, then set the `App ID`, build and run, and get the error below:

> error: failed to launch '/Users/zhanqi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mytest-ggqepovwnaqjfidycsaekzocibxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/mytest.app/mytest' --
>
> No such file or directory (/Users/zhanqi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mytest-ggqepovwnaqjfidycsaekzocibxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/mytest.app/mytest)

I have checked the path below and it does in fact exist. I have reinstalled Xcode three times, but it still doesn't work.
`"/Users/zhanqi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mytest-ggqepovwnaqjfidycsaekzocibxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/mytest.app"`

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: It runs fine in simulator by the way , just not work in iPhone .

Comment: Try cleaning targets in Xcode command-shift-K

Comment: Hi! Same here.. Any Solution??

Answer (score 8):

First clear your DerivedData (/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/) delete every thing from there.

Now restart your XCode, Restart your device.

This might work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I have tried this solution,but unluckily it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, but with deploying to iPad. It was working on the iPad simulator, but not on the device.

Solved it by restarting Xcode.

Comment: 2,at first ,it can appear on my iPhone ,and i tried delete it then run again , or  restart the device .  3 ,delete DerivedData folder. 4 , reinstall Xcode . 5 , even reinstall my mac os and Xcode . They don't work ,the error come again when I set app ID for a new build project. I have no idea  how this happen @@!

Comment: @zhan qi: There were a couple of other things I tried, which may have affected it. I removed the developer profile I had installed on the iPad before. This will make xcode install it for you next time you try to deploy the app to the device. I also made the deployment target the same version as the os on the device. Hope you get it working.

Answer (score 2):

I just had same problem with armv6 device. Finally I found that there was 'armv7' in 'Required device capabilities' in 'Info' tab under target settings - I removed that item from list and now it works.